# Multiple Regex validation for single value - alphanumeric with allowed special characters issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Below is my regex for validating input name -starts with alphanumeric,allowed special characters.
It accepts "sample#@#@invalid" where am validating only allowed ()[].-_& characters.
where am doing wrong any help?

```
if(!/[A-Za-z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._&-]+$/.test(inputText)){
 alert('Field name should be alphanumeric and allowed special characters _ . - [ ] ( ) &');
       }
if(!/^[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputText)){
      alert('Field name must start with an alphanumeric');
 }
```

Comment: Note :these two validations for the same input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of negating the test, use a regular expression that inverts the character class:

```
if(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s)(\][._&-]/.test(inputText)){
```

Since this isn't anchored, it will match any character outside the allowed set anywhere in the input text.

```
function validate() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    if (/[^A-Za-z0-9\s)(\][._&-]/.test(inputText)) {
        alert('Field name should be alphanumeric and alllowed  special characters _ . - [ ] ( ) &');
    }
    if (/^[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputText)) {
        alert('Field name must start with an alphanumeric');
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/H9Euf/1)

Comment: You can remove some redundant escapes: `/[^A-Za-z0-9\s)(\]\[._&-]/`.

Comment: hi barmar, i tried the above regex in jquery validator method ie. instead of if loop.is there any limitation for using ^ instead of !.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with the result of the test. I'd have to see how you're using it.

Comment: Notice that my regular expression is used to match _failing_ input. If the validator wants you to return `true` for success, you have to invert the result.

Comment: Same regex used in validator method [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nilisha7/aeH8p/5/).

Answer (score 0):

This is for start with alphanumeric and then alphanumeric + special characters onwards.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\(\)\[\]._&-]+$/
```

This one is starts with alphanumeric and then only special characters onwards.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9][\(\)\[\]._&-]+$/
```

Notice I have added `$` sign at the end of the regex to make anchor it at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches the "invalid" part of the input string given as this suffixx is perfectly valid based on your given regex. Maybe you should just add a starting `^` character in your regex as in your second one. Then it would not match the given string.

```
if(!/^[A-Za-z0-9\s\)\(\]\[\._&-]+$/.test(inputText)){
    alert('Field name should be alphanumeric and allowed special characters _ . - [ ] ( ) &');

}
if(!/^[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(inputText)){
    alert('Field name must start with an alphanumeric');
}
```

I would of course prefer Sabuj Hassan's answer as it combines both checks into one.

Comment: I need to use both error message for same input field.If i use ^ for 1st one 2nd regex will not execute.